# build tree from json array in javascript with no parent key but a prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, recursion

How would you build tree from a json array in javascript with no parent key or any reference id but by matching a **prefix** `"- "`?

The prefix is incremental upon the depth of tree. for e.g.

```
"- " = level one
"- - " = level two
"- - - " = level three
...
```

There are a few similar questions but no relevant answer has been found yet.

So far, I have done something like below:

```js
var $json = [
  { "id":"11", "text":"CatOne" },
  { "id":"12", "text":"- CatOneSubCat1" },
  { "id":"13", "text":"- CatOneSubCat2" },
  { "id":"14", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat1" },
  { "id":"15", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat2" },
  { "id":"16", "text":"- CatOneSubCat3" },
  { "id":"17", "text":"CatTwo" },
  { "id":"18", "text":"CatThree" },
  { "id":"19", "text":"CatFour" },
  { "id":"20", "text":"- CatFourSubCat1" },
  { "id":"21", "text":"- CatFourSubCat2" },
  { "id":"22", "text":"CatFive" }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $arr = [];
  var $str = "";
  var $prefix = "- "; 

  $.each( $json, function( key, value ) {
    value.children = [];
    // TODO: additional prefix should be appended upon the depth of tree
    if(!value.text.startsWith($prefix)) {
     $arr.push(value);
    }
    else {
     $arr[$arr.length - 1].children.push(value);
    }
  });
  $("#mypre").text(JSON.stringify($arr, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="mypre"></pre>
```

Result from the snippet above:

```
[
    { "id":"11", "text":"CatOne", "children":[
        { "id":"12", "text":"- CatOneSubCat1", "children":[] },
        { "id":"13", "text":"- CatOneSubCat2", "children":[] },
        { "id":"14", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat1", "children":[] },
        { "id":"15", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat2", "children":[] },
        { "id":"16", "text":"- CatOneSubCat3", "children":[] }
    ] },
    { "id":"17", "text":"CatTwo", "children":[] },
    { "id":"18", "text":"CatThree", "children":[] },
    { "id":"19", "text":"CatFour", "children":[
        {"id":"20", "text":"- CatFourSubCat1", "children":[] },
        {"id":"21", "text":"- CatFourSubCat2", "children":[] }
    ] },
    { "id":"22", "text":"CatFive", "children":[] }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    { "id":"11", "text":"CatOne", "children":[
        { "id":"12", "text":"- CatOneSubCat1", "children":[] },
        { "id":"13", "text":"- CatOneSubCat2", "children":[
            { "id":"14", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat1", "children":[] },
            { "id":"15", "text":"- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat2", "children":[] }
        ]},
        { "id":"16", "text":"- CatOneSubCat3", "children":[] }
    ] },
    { "id":"17", "text":"CatTwo", "children":[] },
    { "id":"18", "text":"CatThree", "children":[] },
    { "id":"19", "text":"CatFour", "children":[
        { "id":"20", "text":"- CatFourSubCat1", "children":[] },
        { "id":"21", "text":"- CatFourSubCat2", "children":[] },
    ] },
    { "id":"22", "text":"CatFive", "children":[] }
]
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a *JSON array*. JSON is **always** a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array as reference for the last inserted level objects and iterate the given array whil checking the level.

```js
var data = [{ id: "11", text: "CatOne" }, { id: "12", text: "- CatOneSubCat1" }, { id: "13", text: "- CatOneSubCat2" }, { id: "14", text: "- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat1" }, { id: "15", text: "- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat2" }, { id: "15a", text: "- - -     extra space" }, { id: "16", text: "- CatOneSubCat3" }, { id: "17", text: "CatTwo" }, { id: "18", text: "CatThree" }, { id: "19", text: "CatFour" }, { id: "20", text: "- CatFourSubCat1" }, { id: "21", text: "- CatFourSubCat2" }, { id: "22", text: "CatFive" }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var levels = [{}];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var level = Math.floor(a.text.match(/^(- )*/)[0].length / 2);
            levels.length = level + 1;
            levels[level].children = levels[level].children || [];
            levels[level].children.push(a);
            levels[level + 1] = a;
        });
        return levels[0].children;
    }(data);
  
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `Math.floor("- - -  SS".match(/^([ \-]*)+/)[0].length/2)` returns 4 instead of 3, where `S = "extra space"`.

Comment: what means extra space?

Comment: SO strips the extra spaces so `S` is used as a placeholder, please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rw25p8hh/

Comment: i have now an object with extra space, `{ id: "15a", text: "- - -     extra space" }` it should work with a changed regex now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it using recursion.

I particularly like this answer because there is almost no mental overhead in the main `aux` loop. Because we're building a tree, it makes sense that our process branches off into several iterations of our loop to build the final result.

- If the current node `x` is ever `undefined` or the node depth level *decreases*, we're done iterating for this depth
- If the node depth level stayed the same, find all the nodes at the *next* depth level, **and** continue iterating at the *current* depth level
- otherwise the node depth level increased and we will skip that node for the current depth

Aside from the little `depth` helper function I added (also recursive), there's nothing else to it.

```js
// type Node = Node { id :: String, text :: String, nodes :: [Node] }

// depth :: Node -> Int
const depth = ({ text: [x, y, ...text] }) =>
  (x + y === '- ') ? 1 + depth({ text }) : 0

// buildTree :: [Node] -> [Node]
const buildTree = xs => {
  const aux = (d, [x,...xs]) => {
    if (x === undefined || depth(x) < d)
      return []
    else if (depth(x) === d)
      return [Object.assign({}, x, {nodes: aux(d+1, xs)}), ...aux(d, xs)]
    else
      return aux(d, xs) 
  }
  return aux(0, xs)
}

const nodes = [
  { id: '11', text: 'CatOne' },
  { id: '12', text: '- CatOneSubCat1' },
  { id: '13', text: '- CatOneSubCat2' },
  { id: '14', text: '- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat1' },
  { id: '15', text: '- - CatOneSubCat2SubCat2' },
  { id: '16', text: '- CatOneSubCat3' },
  { id: '17', text: 'CatTwo' },
  { id: '18', text: 'CatThree' },
  { id: '19', text: 'CatFour' },
  { id: '20', text: '- CatFourSubCat1' },
  { id: '21', text: '- CatFourSubCat2' },
  { id: '22', text: 'CatFive' }
]

const tree = buildTree(nodes)

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, '  '))
```